# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(BootModule)[BsDropdownDirective -> AnimationBuilder]: NullInjectorError: No provider for AnimationBuilder

Tags: typescript, angular8, ngx-bootstrap

i'am working with angular 8 and and the version 5.3.2 of ngx-bootstrap, i would implement a navbar but i had a problem of a  " NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(BootModule)" for every ngx-bootstrap's module added

app.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [collapse]=isCollapsed>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown" dropdown>
 <a href="#" dropdownToggle class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <li class="dropdown" dropdown>
 <a href="#" dropdownToggle class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

app.component.ts

`isCollapsed = true;`

and the app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbAccordionModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CollapseModule, BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbAccordionModule,
    CollapseModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Import the BrowserAnimationsModule and BrowserModule in AppModule.
2. And also use a shared module to import 'CommonModule'. Create a new module 
   as below.

> shared.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { NgbAccordionModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CollapseModule, BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbAccordionModule,
    CollapseModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: when i add  BrowserAnimationsModule this error appears : " BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead "

Comment: This is because 'CommonModule' also export 'BrowserModule'. Therefore import 'CommonModule' in shared module and import that shared module to AppModule. I have changed the code accordingly.

Comment: If it is working, please mark it as correct.Thank you.